# PayPal transaction from with in Windows Phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, paypal, windows-phone-8

We are building a shopping app (yes not many on windows phone store), it's basically as it would be like you will go to a store, select a product, pay with your paypal and give your shipping address and that's it!

Problem is the app is rejected twice, both time with same reason:

"Comments: The user is prompted for payment information (credit card) from within the application. Transactions must occur external to the application via a secure (HTTPS) website, or through a hosted control that allows the user to verify the URL and HTTPS security. "

As the only payment method is by PayPal and we are using PayPal standard which means we have to go to the PayPal hosted page for transaction. First time we got rejected we just included a field where user would be able to see the URL of where he is going. User was able to see https:// as well to see if the transaction was secure. Now we just added a lock icon (forced image, it's not coming automatically as it would in browser) in that URL address bar instead of https://. We are just wondering if that would not be enough as well? and we have to open the paypal page in browser?

A screen shot is attached. I will be grateful for any help.

[image]

Comment: It is proving to be a multi-million dollar question so far.. here is the thread on official Windows Phone forums, you can read the whole story http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpsubmit/thread/c37e402c-c10f-4417-addb-128bcefa7745

Comment: Microsoft apparantely updated their Submission policy guidelines on May 31st, 2013 .. it now states the exact same wordings which they were giving when rejecting apps but still does not say anything about payment collection related to physical goods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184841(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: and paypal now has an official SDK to support payments on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft's acceptance policy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PayPal Mobile Express Checkout method with the help of a webbrowser control.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout

Hope the above links will help you.

**Edit:**

You could use the web browser task to initiate payment process.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("https://www.paypal.com/....", UriKind.Absolute);
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Comment: The WebBrowser control does not provide the ability to view URLs or a secure lock icon, which Windows store policy team is asking for. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462081(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Otherwise you a browser task to initiate the payment process in the Internet Explorer on Windows phone. Check my edited answer.

Comment: That is what we were forced to do at the end. App is in the windows phone store now but we are not happy with this solution as it breaks the app experience.

Comment: @HammadTariq So by spinning up a web browser and using the tools for the web browser stated above you solved the problem and the app passed submition?

Comment: Yes, two of them passed the submission, open a browser, pass your data to it and finish shopping there.